# Applescript: Open a new Safari tab from a display dialog box

Tags: applescript

I would like to open a new tab on Safari from a display dialog box with a dynamic URL

Basically only the last digits of the URL are changing, the end has to come from the user

```
## dialogue box##
set theResponse to display dialog "Show me the ID" default answer "" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue"

## Open URL##

set myURL to "https://myURL/"
on open location myURL
    set URL to myURL & theResponse
    tell application "Safari" to open URL
end open location
```

The box works perfectly and I see in the Script Editor that the results is taken into account:

```
tell application "Script Editor"
    display dialog "Show me the ID" default answer "" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue"
        {button returned:"Continue", text returned:"123456"}
```

I'm just not sure how to open the URL from 2 different sources and what format I should use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are only a couple of URLs you could just use buttons, for example `{"Cancel", "Continue with X", "Continue with Y"}, and use different URLs based on the button and text returned.

```
on run
    set response to (display dialog "Show me the ID" default answer "" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Continue with X", "Continue with Y"} default button "Continue with Y")
    if button returned of response is "Continue with X" then
        set baseURL to "https://URLx/"
    else -- Continue with Y
        set baseURL to "https://URLy/"
    end if
    openNewTab(baseURL & text returned of response)
end run

on openNewTab(myURL)
    tell application "Safari"
        activate
        tell window 1 to set current tab to (make new tab with properties {URL:myURL})
    end tell
end openNewTab
```

Comment: thank you so much! this is exactly what I needed. I adapted the code to be able to open 3 tabs with one click and that does the trick.